# How do I re-use the default android title gradient?

Tags: android, android-layout

If you create an activity and set a label without disabling the title bar you will see a title that uses a gradient as a background. Is there a way for me to re-use this resource without re-implementing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the background for this comes from the resource that is called "activity_title_bar.9.png" that is in the system drawable folder.

Here is a copy of it: [image: title 9 patch]

If you download it from here you'll have to rename it using the .9.png suffix. You can also find it in your SDK. The path is "SDK\platforms\android-4\data\res\drawable"

Note android-4 could be any other number that you happen to have installed on your machine.

Generally if you are wanting to use a system resource like this best practice is to save your own copy of it and include it in your project. Resources like this are subject to change at any time with new versions of the OS (or even with device specific skins that Manufacturers add on to the OS) So if you rely on the system copy from inside your app then you have no way to know for sure that it will look the same across all devices.